# How to hide/show fields in a better way

Tags: javascript, aura, lightning-layouts

I'm trying to hide & show multiple fields based on a radio button change. and I'm able to achieve this by controlling the layout item visibility. But the main problem the fields are displayed in different areas. So, UI looks bad.

My Aura component.

```
<div class="c-container slds-theme_default slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="space">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" >
                <lightning:radioGroup name="radioGroup"
                          label="Radio Group"
                          options="{! v.options }"
                          type="radio"
                          disabled="false"
                          onchange="{!c.handleChange }"
                          variant="label-hidden" />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" class="slds-hidden" aura:id="monthtab">
                        <lightning:select aura:id="select" name="select" label="Select a pie"  variant="label-hidden" class="slds-show_inline-block">
                    <option value="Last Month">Last Month</option>
                    <option value="This Month">This Month</option>
                    <option value="Next Month">Next Month</option>
                </lightning:select>          
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" class="slds-hidden" aura:id="datetab">
                From: 
                <lightning:input type="date" variant="label-hidden" name="input1" label="" />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" class="slds-hidden" aura:id="datetab">
                To: 
                <lightning:input type="date" variant="label-hidden" name="input1" label="" />     
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
```

By date option:
[image]

By Month option:
[image]

You can see there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the [slds-hide](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/#Hide-Show) class instead of [slds-hidden](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/#Hidden-Visible). It should hide the element but preserve the position, so it should not affect the displaying.